# search filter with PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, predicatebuilder

I'm working in search filter
we choose a student ( multiple checkbox )and get its exams and some exams can have two students
for one student it works but when I choose multiple student I get exception The LINQ expression 'DbSet
.Where(c => True && False || Invoke(r => r.listofStudents.Select(c => c.id).Contains(__broker_0), c[Exam])
&& False || Invoke(r => r.listofStudents.Select(c => c.id).Contains(__student_0), c[Exam])
|| Invoke(r => r.listofStudents.Select(c => c.id).Contains(__student_1), c[Exam])
)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
this is the code

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Exam>();
  var predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.False<Exam>();
 if (students.Count < 2)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(r => r.listofStudents.Select(c => c.id).Contains(students.FirstOrDefault()));
                }
                else
                {
                        
                foreach (var student in students)
                {
                    predicate1 = predicate1.Or(r => r.listofStudents.Select(c => c.id).Contains(student ));
                    predicate = predicate.And(predicate1);
                }
                           
            }
 reqQuery = reqQuery.Where(predicate);
```

thank you

Comment: Could you share your model desgin?It could work well in my project.And what is your `listofStudents` and `students` and `reqQuery `?Also,what is your version of efcore and asp.net core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem

```
 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Exam>();
  var predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.False<Exam>();
 if (students.Count < 2)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(r => r.listofStudents.Select(c => c.id).Contains(students.FirstOrDefault()));
                }
                else
                {
                        
                foreach (var student in students)
                {
                    predicate1 = predicate1.Or(r => r.listofStudents.Select(c => c.id).Contains(student ));
                }
                           
            }
 reqQuery = reqQuery.Where(predicate).Where(predicate1);
```